# Help with a SQL MINUS statement

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, Reporter_Vacation, Dropper, Vacation_Temp.

Reporter_Vacation has Reporter, Start_dt, End_dt   (the 3 combined are unique)

Dropper has Dropper_ID and Reporter   (both are unique)

Vacation_Temp has Dropper_ID, Start_dt, End_dt   (the 3 combined are unique)

How can I find what Reporter, Start_dt, and End_dt are in Vacation_Temp that are not in Reporter_Vacation?

```
SELECT DROPPER_ID, BEGIN_DT, END_DT 
FROM VACATION_TEST
    MINUS 
SELECT DROPPER.DROPPER_ID, REPORTER_VACATION.BEGIN_DT, REPORTER_VACATION.END_DT 
FROM REPORTER_VACATION, DROPPER 
WHERE DROPPER.REPORTER = REPORTER_VACATION.REPORTER;
```

Comment: -1 Well, *what happens*? (You have at least one typo in the above -- but running the query would say what.)

Comment: And do you want the reporter, or dropper_id (because you say you want one, but are selecting the other)?

Comment: X-Zero, I want Reporter, sorry about that typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach that is more standardised and more indexable (hence often faster) than MINUS is a null-join.

Use a LEFT JOIN to bring in the table you don't want, leaving NULL where there is no value in the table. Then test for that NULL in the WHERE clause. Expanding that to two joined tables:

```
SELECT vacation_test.dropper_id, vacation_test.begin_dt, vacation_test.end_dt
FROM vacation_test
    LEFT JOIN dropper ON
        dropper.dropper_id=vacation_test.dropper_id
    LEFT JOIN reporter_vacation ON
        reporter_vacation.dropper_id=dropper.dropper_id AND
        reporter_vacation.begin_dt=vacation_test.begin_dt AND
        reporter_vacation.end_dt=vacation_test.end_dt
WHERE reporter_vacation.begin_dt IS NULL
```